# JasperReports Imprime valores repetidos al hacer INNER JOIN Doble

Tags: sql, join, jasper-reports, ireport, jasper

[image: Estas son mis tablas]

Este es mi código de consulta

```
SELECT
     FACTURA."ID" AS FACTURA_ID,
     FACTURA."CLIENTEID" AS FACTURA_CLIENTEID,
     FACTURA."USUARIOID" AS FACTURA_USUARIOID,
     FACTURA."FECHA" AS FACTURA_FECHA,
     FACTURA."TOTAL" AS FACTURA_TOTAL,
     VENTAPRODUCTO."ID" AS VENTAPRODUCTO_ID,
     VENTAPRODUCTO."PRODUCTOID" AS VENTAPRODUCTO_PRODUCTOID,
     VENTAPRODUCTO."FACTURAID" AS VENTAPRODUCTO_FACTURAID,
     VENTAPRODUCTO."CANTIDAD" AS VENTAPRODUCTO_CANTIDAD,
     VENTAPRODUCTO."PRECIOVENTA" AS VENTAPRODUCTO_PRECIOVENTA,
     VENTASERVICIO."ID" AS VENTASERVICIO_ID,
     VENTASERVICIO."SERVICIOID" AS VENTASERVICIO_SERVICIOID,
     VENTASERVICIO."FACTURAID" AS VENTASERVICIO_FACTURAID,
     VENTASERVICIO."PRECIOVENTA" AS VENTASERVICIO_PRECIOVENTA,
     VENTASERVICIO."CANTIDAD" AS VENTASERVICIO_CANTIDAD
FROM
     "USUARIO"."FACTURA" FACTURA INNER JOIN "USUARIO"."VENTAPRODUCTO" VENTAPRODUCTO ON FACTURA."ID" = VENTAPRODUCTO."FACTURAID"
     INNER JOIN "USUARIO"."VENTASERVICIO" VENTASERVICIO ON FACTURA."ID" = VENTASERVICIO."FACTURAID"
```

Esta consulta devuelve valores duplicados, entonces en el reporte yo deseleciono la casilla "Imprimir valores repetidos" en todos los campos, lo cual funciona para VENTA_PRODUCTO pero los valores de la tabla VENTA_SERVICIO se visualizan repetidos.

[image: Valores repetidos]

Comment: Así como muestras el modelo, me hace pensar que te falta incorporar una entidad más que relacione cada producto y/o servicio con un ítem o línea de la factura, podrías confirmarnos esto?

Comment: Buenas noches, Si tengo dos entidades adicionales, una para productos y otra para servicios, solo que intente ser lo más puntual posible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Veamos, lo que te puedo decir viendo el modelo que solo consta de tres tablas, es que tienes una relación entre Facturas <-> Servicios (1-N) y entre Facturas <-> Productos (1-N), pero la relación ternaria entre Servicios <-> Productos <-> Factura (N-M) requiere otra tabla. Como te decía en mi comentario, yo creo que te esta faltando una entidad que defina como se relacionan Productos y Servicios dentro de la factura, algo tipo `FacturasItems` o `FacturasLineas` (solo a modo de ejemplo). Voy a responderte de todas formas, por que puede serte útil.

Me imagino que en la realidad puedes facturar servicios y/o productos y eventualmente solo servicios o solo productos. Por esto, tal como lo planteas la falla está en el `JOIN` que haces, de hecho NO debes hacer un `join` entre ambas tablas.

Supongamos que en la factura 1 has incorporado los productos P1 y P2 y el servicio S3, la salida tal como la tienes planteada mediante dos `INNER JOIN` sería:

```
Factura Producto Servicio
======= ======== ========
1       P1       S3
1       P2       S3
```

Esto te puede dar la idea errónea de que el servicio S3 está "duplicado". Un caso peor, sería si no has facturado por ejemplo un servicio y sí un producto, en ese caso la consulta no devolvería registros.

La forma deseable de ver los datos debiera ser:

```
Factura Tipo      Producto/Servicio
======= ========= =================
1       Producto  P1
1       Producto  P2
1       Servicio  S3
```

#### ¿Como lo armamos?

Si imaginamos que conceptualmente una factura tiene "Items" facturados y que los "Items" pueden ser Productos y/o Servicios entonces deberías tener un consulta que "uniera" los productos y servicios y recién ahí realizar el `JOIN`. Como en tu modelo no tienes esta entidad o tabla, vamos a simular esto mediante un `UNION`.

No conozco a fondo `JasperReports` pero deberías poder armar una consulta `SQL` usando un `UNION` entre Productos y Servicios, algo así:

```
SELECT  FACTURA."ID"         AS FACTURA_ID,
        FACTURA."CLIENTEID"  AS FACTURA_CLIENTEID,
        FACTURA."USUARIOID"  AS FACTURA_USUARIOID,
        FACTURA."FECHA"      AS FACTURA_FECHA,
        FACTURA."TOTAL"      AS FACTURA_TOTAL,
        -- detalle de los ítems facturados
        PRODUCTOSERVCICIO.TIPO,
        PRODUCTOSERVCICIO.ID,
        PRODUCTOSERVCICIO.VENTAPRODUCTO_PRODUCTOSERVICIO_ID,
        PRODUCTOSERVCICIO.CANTIDAD,
        PRODUCTOSERVCICIO.PRECIOVENTA

FROM    "USUARIO"."FACTURA" FACTURA
INNER JOIN (    SELECT   'PRODUCTO'                 AS TIPO,
                         VENTAPRODUCTO."FACTURAID"  AS FACTURAID,
                         VENTAPRODUCTO."ID"         AS ID,
                         VENTAPRODUCTO."PRODUCTOID" AS VENTAPRODUCTO_PRODUCTOSERVICIO_ID,
                         VENTAPRODUCTO."CANTIDAD"   AS CANTIDAD,
                         VENTAPRODUCTO."PRECIOVENTA"    AS PRECIOVENTA
                         FROM "USUARIO"."VENTAPRODUCTO" VENTAPRODUCTO 

                UNION

                SELECT  'SERVICIO'                  AS TIPO,
                        VENTASERVICIO."FACTURAID"   AS FACTURAID,
                        VENTASERVICIO."ID"          AS ID,
                        VENTASERVICIO."SERVICIOID"  AS VENTAPRODUCTO_PRODUCTOSERVICIO_ID,
                        VENTASERVICIO."CANTIDAD"    AS CANTIDAD,
                        VENTASERVICIO."PRECIOVENTA" AS PRECIOVENTA
                        FROM "USUARIO"."VENTASERVICIO" VENTASERVICIO 
             ) PRODUCTOSERVCICIO
             ON PRODUCTOSERVCICIO.FACTURAID = FACTURA."ID"
```

Obviamente sin el modelo completo y datos de ejemplo, no puedo asegurarte que tal como está escrito funcione, pero espero sirva para comprender como realizar la consulta.

Comment: gracias, me ayudo bastante